# 2 SQL statements need to convert into only one statement

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to select data from 2 tables with one condition.

My statement:

```
SELECT * from A where date >= ?  AND  date <= ?   UNION ALL SELECT * from B where date >= ?  AND  date <= ?
```

When I use this statement, my application needs a delay of 2 seconds to show data correctly,

But when i use :

```
SELECT * from A    UNION ALL SELECT * from B
```

It's no need for the delay ,

So how can I get the data with more speed statement ?

I also tried :

```
SELECT * from(SELECT * from A   UNION ALL SELECT * from B) where date >= ?  AND  date <= ? "
```

but it's also slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into creating a "prepared" or "compiled" statement?  This can be especially effective when you have conditions like you have.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

How many rows in your result set?

Comment: oh , i got it , the problem was about wrong date on my condition , i was adding a row at "now" date , and search for records before 1 second from now ,